# What happened to the "Run" and "Run On" commands in Visual Studio 2010 Database Projects?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2010, database-project

I have migrated a database project from VS2008 to VS2010.  While in VS08, I used to be able to right-click on a .sql or .cmd file and select a "Run" or "Run On" command from the context menu.

In VS2010, though, these menu items seem to have gone away.

I have a number of .sql and .cmd scripts that I am used to being able to run directly from the Visual Studio IDE.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Infuriating that they left off functionality that was widely used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately they have not been implemented (much to the annoyance of developers)

MS say:

> Unfortunately we were unable to add
>   the right click on database
>   reference/server explorer conx to the
>   product.

More details at:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstsdb/thread/f374c604-a7eb-496d-a261-9374790cdbf9

Comment: yeah, that was my post.  Unfortunately, not much of an answer on Microsoft's part.

Comment: Steve, I post this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004483/vs2010-macro-add-in-for-run-and-run-on-commands-in-visual-studio-2010 which you may have seen.  Not sure if this is an avenue worth pursuing?

Answer (score 1):

Open the sql source you want to execute. Now, right click in the editor and select "Execute SQL". First time you will be asked to connect to a database. If you want to execute on a second database you have to right click and select "Connection->Disconnect" first.